# Excel: dynamically numeric Dropdown

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

i want to create in excel an dropdown to vote for something like

"how important is the weather for You"

and the user can choose from 1 to 10

BUT

the I want to give the user the possibility to change the range

for example

From 1 - 10
To 1 - 5

therefore I have to fields in my excel sheet

From: 
To:

and the user can add there some values and exactly these values I want to display then in my dropdown box?

How can I do this?

I have alreay found many solution for standart dropdowns like

Choose your car!

VW
BMW
Mercedes

and then i can create a dropdown based on a source column, but in this case i want to fill my dropdown with a FROM - TO Range

for any hints I would be really happy!

Thank you very much!

greetz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [Dynamic Named Range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830287).

In this case, I created a column on a sheet with the heading Scale.

- In the first cell I wrote `=From` (a named range based on the `From` cell).
- In the second cell I wrote the formula `=IF(G2="","",IF(G2+1>To,"",G2+1))` where `To` is a named range based on the `To` cell. (The column I used was G in my example).
- I then dragged down the formula for a bunch of rows (however many you need for the range).
- I then created a Named Range (Scale) with the formula: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!G2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$G:$G)-1,1)` (-1 is to exclude header row)
- Then create a Data Validation on the drop-down cell = to Scale. You will see the values pop up between From and To based on whatever entries are in that cell.